# TS2322: Type 'Promise<Hero | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Hero>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm learning angular4 from [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5).
Below is a function to get a hero from service's function:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // Simulate server latency with 2 second delay
            setTimeout(() => resolve(HEROES), 2000);
        });
    }

    getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {

        if (id < 0) {
            throw new Error('Hero is not found.');
        }
        return this.getHeroes()
            .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }
}
```

On execution it throws error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Promise<Hero | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Hero>'.
Type 'Hero | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.
```

Anybody else also faced this issue ? Please help.
Thank you.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hero-detail',
    templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html'
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() hero: Hero;

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap
            .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.heroService.getHero(+(params.get('id') || -1)))
            .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
    }

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post `this.getHeroes()` method and `Hero` interface .

Comment: There should be Hero class in your code. and you should import it where you use. Wherever this function is put import { Hero } from 'Hero.ts' (be careful about path) and then try again.

Comment: It throws error because heroes.find could return undefined.

Comment: @Shelly can you post your component code or where ever you called the `getHero` method. So it can help us to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Rajez thank you. I added.

Comment: Okay i will try to reproduce the error

Comment: what is `HEROES`? try adding an explicit type to the promise constructor: `return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve => {`

Comment: @Sahuagin HEROES is in mock-heroes.ts.

Comment: Do you mean that that is not your file? I see a file with that name at https://gist.github.com/kotazi/d3b073e5f33ff8ef1605 . Is that what your file looks like?

Comment: @Sahuagin I used [angular sample code](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt5/toh-pt5.zip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason typescript throws this error is because `Array.find` will **return `undefined`** when **all elements don't matched the condition** `hero.id === id`.

Refer **[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** about `Array.find`:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. **Otherwise undefined is returned.**

---

To avoid the error, you should change your function's return type to `Promise<Hero | undefined>`.

```
getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero | undefined> {    // <----mention here for return type
  return this.getHeroes()
             .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}
```

Comment: I tried.
TS2322: Type 'Hero | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Hero'.

Comment: @Shelly it should of work. Give me one minute, I'll confirm at my local.

Comment: @Shelly I reproduce your problem and confirm this way will solve the error you have posted. Anyway, If this don't solve your problem, I'll delete my answer in order to not confusing others.

Comment: what's version of typescript do you use??

Comment: @Shelly currently 2.4.0.

Comment: I used 2.4.1 with Visual Studio 2017. I will try another way to build this project.

Comment: @Shelly I have upated my local typescript to latest(2.5.1) and then your problem seems won't happen at my local even without my suggestions(I don't know what changed about this :P). Have a try. :-)

Comment: This does not seem to cause the error for me. What he's shown of his code seems to work (minus the angular stuff which I'm not sure of).

Comment: I changed hero-detail.component.ts 
.subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero)
to
.subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero || <Hero>{})
then your answer is work.

Comment: I used angular-cli to build the project and it doesn't throw this exception. My project is created by Microsoft ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services. I don't know what's different when building typescript, but it should use the same typescript version, right ?

Comment: @Shelly I don't use Visual studio, but AFAIR, it has an build-in typescript version.

Comment: @Pengyy I know. But project's TypeScriptCompileBlocked is true, and webpack.config.js contains typescript loader.  

`{ test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' }`